# Custom Shadows on Android

Tags: android, xml, shadow, pixel-perfect

Hi I have a design on zeplin, that implements a custom shadow that I'm trying to replay on Native Android and it is not enough with elevation,

The shadow on zeplin has these properties:

[image]

Comment: You will have to design a custom shape that emulates the shadow and set it as background.

Comment: ´@BogdanAndroid thanks, and, you know if that shape is reusable, for components with different sizes?

Comment: You are welcome, yes it should be, it's just a xml component that you set as background of your views.